# Elasticsearch: Query String vs Simple Query String

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

What is the exact difference between Query String and Simple Query String? The only difference that is mentioned in the docs is that **Query String is more advanced but throws an exception when a sent query cannot be parsed.**

However, I've noticed that Query String behave differently even if there isn't any exception in the query string.

Here are two same queries but the one with query string returns a response and the simple query string returns zero documents. I want to know what is going on behind the curtain.

```
{ 
 "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": [
        {
           "query_string": {
           "query": "Atoms for Peace",
           "default_operator": "AND"
      
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 }
}
```

```
{ 
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": [
      {
        "simple_query_string": {
          "query": "Atoms for Peace",
          "default_operator": "AND"
        }
      }
    ]

  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include `explain=true` query param in your search endpoint, this will give you detailed response on what tokens are created for your search terms and why your results are different in both the queries.

Comment: The computation with both queries looks fairly similar. The same formulas are being used for the frequency of occurrence, IDF, and boost. I'm really confused about what is causing different results.

Comment: @sheharbano can you share index mapping,. sample documents

Comment: No, the problem hasn't been solved yet. Here's the document that I'm trying to search https://api.vam.ac.uk/v2/museumobject/O696516

Comment: @sheharbano its really big document, can you provide a smaller document to showcase your issue